# Pairwise independent hash functions in Java

Tags: java, hash, universal-hashing

I'm looking for a quick and easy way to use a [(universal) family of pairwise independent hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing) in my Java projects.

Ideally, I would have some object `UniversalFamily` (representing the Family) which would return me objects with a method `hash()` which hashes integers.

Example usage:

```
// use this object to generate pairwise independent hash functions
UniversalFamily family = new UniversalFamily();

// these objects represent the pairwise independent hash functions
HashF hashF1 = fam.getHashFunction();
HashF hashF2 = fam.getHashFunction();
// ...

/* here the hash functions are being used to hash the integers 1, 2 and 
   1337, the return values (not stored) are the results of the 
   corresponding hash functions. */
hashF1.hash(1);
hashF1.hash(2);
hashF2.hash(1337);
// ...
```

Before I start tinkering around, is there anything like this already available?

Comment: `hashF2.hash(1337);` what is `1337` in this example ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi An integer, I'm interested in hashing integers.

Comment: I'm afraid that this may be too broad and off-topic, since you're sorta asking for a recommendation. Anyways, I cannot find adequate line in help section, and personally like the clarity of your question (and amount of work I see you're putting into editing), so I won't flag it. Good luck.

Comment: ok so that is input to your function. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html is closest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
/* Used to generate and encapsulate pairwise independent hash functions.
See see https://people.csail.mit.edu/ronitt/COURSE/S12/handouts/lec5.pdf , claim 5 for more information.
 */
private static class HashF {

    private final int a;
    private final int b;
    private final int p = 1610612741; // prime

    HashF(int a, int b) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        this.a = rand.nextInt(p);
        this.b = rand.nextInt(p);
    }

    // hashes integers
    public int hash(int x) {
        return (a*x + b) % p;
    }

}
```